# How to use joomla plugins

Tags: google-maps, joomla1.5

I've managed to install a Google map plugin but don't know how to get it to display on certain pages.

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and have installed this plugin:

http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla-Gadgets/googleDirections-plugin.php#latest

I've configured the plugin (added my api key, set the dimensions), but can't find a way to get it to display on the page. I've tried to add the following code to an article but no map is displayed:

```
{googleDir from="1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View CA 94043" 
to="701 First Avenue, Sunnyvale, CA 94089"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative use this plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1147/details

Much better documentation and very straight forward to use!

Answer (score 1):

1. I almost hate to ask this, but have you verified that the plugin is enabled? Most Joomla plugins are not enabled upon install.
2. Are you using PHP5? If you're using PHP4, the plugin won't work.
3. From the plugin's page: **Important: the googleDirections plugin now makes use of the googleMaps plugin to display the map. So please make sure you have installed the googleMaps plugin for this plugin to work.**